# How to get lexer to output EOF in Scala TokenParser?

Tags: parsing, scala

If I define a `Lexical` to feed a `TokenParser`, I'm having trouble getting the `TokenParser` to actually output an `EOF` token. In particular, some of the methods in `Parser[T]` (`acceptIf`, `acceptMatch`, and `phrase`) directly check whether the `Reader` is `atEnd`, so there's no chance for an `EOF` token to get added to the token stream before an error is returned.

Since the `Tokens` trait actually defines an `EOF` token, I'm sure there must be some simple way to output it, but at this point all I can think to do is to create my own `Reader` that doesn't return `true` for `atEnd` until after at least one `EOF` has been output or adding a `'\032'` character to the input so that the `Reader` doesn't realize it's at the end until after it has emitted that character.

Please tell me I'm missing an easier way...

Comment: I still can't figure out how to get EOF from the lexer, but I was able to create a parser that recognizes the end-of-file in the `TokenParser`, which means I can do the parsing I was trying to do. So the question is more for academic interest, now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do this at all. Use

```
new YourLexical.Scanner("foo")
```

to create a Reader[YourLexical.Token], which will respond to #atEnd automatically.

Then you can hand this Reader to a TokenParser implementing your syntax directly as input:

```
class YourTokenParser ... {
    ...
    def program: Parser[...] = ...

    def parse(s: String) =
        phrase(program)(new YourLexical.Scanner(s))
}
```

Comment: The problem was that some constructs in my grammar can't be identified unless they're followed by some kind of separation. EOF would count as that separation, but I have to require something after them or they get over-recognized.

Comment: OK revisiting this, I played around quite a bit with it in the past weeks. I still think you can use phrase(), just not at top level, use it as an alternate to your "myconstruct ~ sep" rule: " | phrase(myconstruct)".

Comment: I also found that using the higher abstractions like rep1sep(), into(), etc. help a lot not to fall into left recursion or bad performance pitfalls, and especially rep1sep could help your sep or EOF problem.

Comment: Good point about the performance issues. I was using a `PackratParser`, so I was hoping that all the left recursion would just magically get taken care of.